# what decreases with less current in a dc motor?

Tags: voltage

Torque and or Power. Are they the same ? 
shunt - field windings connected in parallel with armature used for constant torque application.
series - field windings connected in series used for high start torque. so which of this provide "high torque" capability.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be answered by looking up *Torque* and *Power* on wikipedia, and you don't show any attempt at solving this on your own. That's not how EE.SE works.

Comment: the answers were confusing where there were several answers saying different things. no specifying the answer correctly

Comment: You've got a textbook that gives you formulas. Find them. Write them down. Ask exactly what you don't understand about those. Then pass the exam!

Comment: Torque and power are both basic concepts. Asking if they are the same shows no research effort whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Torque and power are related, but they are not the same thing. Power is torque multiplied by speed. High starting torque means that the torque required to break the load loose and initiate rotation from standstill is significantly higher (more than 25 to 50% higher) than the torque required for normal operation. Just stating "high torque" is meaningless without specifying a comparison. A series DC motor has a torque vs speed capability curve with the highest torque at stall and decreasing torque as speed increases. Therefore it is more suitable than a shunt connected DC motor. Torque in a DC motor is generally proportional to current.